Keycloak. Logout user out if idle timeout is exceed
I set SSO Session Idle to 2 minutes and Access Token Lifespan to 1 minute, but if a user is idle for longer than 2 + 2 minutes, keycloak will not logout the user.
So I implement logic to update the token and if it fails user should be logged out, but it never happens, it seems that updateTokne update access and refresh token.
setInterval(() => {
  keycloak.updateToken(-1).then(function (refreshed) {
    if (refreshed) {
      console.log('Token was successfully refreshed');
    } else {
      console.log('Token is still valid');
    }
  }).catch(function () {
    auth.logout();
    console.log('Failed to refresh the token, or the session has expired');
  });
}, 30000);

So, my question is! How to logout user if user has excess idle time?
Shouldn't that be done as part of a feature?
